# What are the necessary JBoss Tools for jBPM?

Tags: jboss, eclipse-plugin, jbpm

I need to make a simple HelloWorld by jBPM under Ecplise so I must prepare my environment for making jBPM working. But I get many selected "Features", and it seems I don't need many of them. However I can't really get the ones needed in my context.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create jBPM project without using any tool. If you use maven you just need to add the jbpm dependencies to your project and work.

Answer (score 0):

JBDS has tools for JBPM built in I believe. If not, there should be a plugin you can download from JBoss Central. https://www.jboss.org/products/devstudio.html